# Is there any react-native library which can connect a to a DSLR camera thru USB OTG cable?

Tags: react-native

I want to connect a mobile device to a DSLR camera via OTG USB cable and retrieve the images from the DSLR camera, is there any react-native library which can do this?

I have tried https://github.com/mapaiva/react-native-usbserial, the getDeviceListAsync() can return the device info, but when call the openDeviceAsync() function, it return the error below:

```
{"framesToPop":1,"nativeStackAndroid": [{"methodName":"getUsbSerialDriver" ,"lineNumber":166,"file": "ReactUsbSerialModule.java"} ,{"methodName":"openDeviceAsync" ,"lineNumber":76,"file":"ReactUsbSerialModule java"},{"methodName":"invoke" ,"lineNumber":-2,"file":"Method.java"} ,{"methodName":"invoke","lineNumber": 372,"file":"JavaMethodWrapperjava"} ,{"methodName":"invoke","lineNumber": 158,"file":"JavaModuleWrapperjava"} ,{"methodName":"run","lineNumber":-2,"file": "NativeRunnable.java"},{"methodName": "handleCallback","lineNumber":873 ,"file":"Handlerjava"},{"methodName": "dispatchMessage","lineNumber":99 ,"file":"Handlerjava"},{"methodName": "dispatchMessage","lineNumber":29,"file": "MessageQueueThreadHandlerjava"} ,{"methodName":"loop","lineNumber":201 ,"file":"LooperjavalruserInfo":null,"code": "EUNSPECIFIED","line":1730,"column":26 ,"sourceURI1:"http://localhost:8081/index .bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify= false")
```

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you find a library?